# Are there arithmetical tests analogues for graphical test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I learned in statistics basic course that sometimes one can make reasoning about the data by making graphical plots, like testing outliers or P-P-plot or Q-Q-plot. But are there some test which measures the same things by numbers? Like what can one do if he or she have to analyze some data in a computer that don't have graphical desktop installed?

Comment: Are you saying you're on a machine with *no* graphical capability at all? What's "*graphical desktop*" and why do you think you need it? (Are you working under Linux?)

Comment: I think there might be situations where it is not clear for the graphics whether or not some point is outlier or not, so a numerical value might make the reasoning 100 % valid. And I can imagine some huge datasets where it is not clear what points are outliers.

And yes, I'm working under Linux with GUI but for me it is easier to compare numbers than pixels.

Comment: Graphics like a QQ plot contain information corresponding to many numbers (dozens to thousands). A single number doesn't easily contain the information in many.

Comment: But aren't there situations where one has to modify the data set by programming and detecting by the code whether or not there are outliers etc.?

Comment: Is your question not about a numerical summary of a display, but in fact about outlier detection? An outlier is usually an indication that the model (for the process by which the sample arose) is lacking (it doesn't describe the data). (Generally in that situation, better models are called for, not mangling the data to fit the model.) Which situations are you in, where you find a need to remove or otherwise alter data values?

Comment: I haven't yet met any such situation yet. My ultimate goal is just to learn statistics so well that I will never need figures to display data, I just hope to learn to reason everything from the numbers, as it is far more easy to put numbers to LaTeX-document that make plots.

Comment: "*learn statistics so well that I will never need figures to display data*" --- *all* the people that I know that really "know statistics well" use graphical displays *constantly*. "*as it is far more easy to put numbers to LaTeX-document that make plots*" -- that's about the worst reason for avoiding plots I have ever seen. Firstly, it's not at all hard to put plots in LaTeX documents, and R (and RStudio) make it much easier still (via things like [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/), for example, which has a whole *manual* specifically on including graphics)... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... and secondly, even if you don't include a graphic in a document, that doesn't mean you are better off never to see it!

Comment: Before `\Sexpr` it was harder to put numbers into LaTeX documents than it was to put graphs. In any case, graphs are important even for inference. Quite a lot of statistical analysis could be described as splitting into (1) formal tests on or estimates of quantities of primary interest, & (2) less formal assessments of the assumptions on which the validity of those tests & estimates depends. Qualitative graphical methods play a large role in 2, not because any particular violation can't be treated quantitatively, but because the modes of violation are innumerable.

Comment: [Anscombe's quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombes_quartet) might be instructive.